# How to avoid pivot by index after groupby.apply?

Tags: pandas

I am currently working on timeseries data and want to calculate the difference in value between days. This has to happen individually for all instances of a given dimension. Here is a sample data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.to_datetime(["2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-04"]), 
               "dim_1": [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
               "value": [50, 100, 70, 120, 150, 110, 130, 200]})
```

For every date, dim_1 combination there is value. Now I came up with the following solution:

```
df.set_index("date").groupby(["dim_1"])\
    .apply(lambda x: x["value"] - x["value"].shift())
```

Resulting in:

```
date   2017-01-01  2017-01-02  2017-01-03  2017-01-04
dim_1                                                
0             NaN        20.0        80.0       -20.0
1             NaN        20.0       -10.0        90.0
```

Now I have to melt the dataframe in order to get my expected result:

```
pd.melt(df.set_index("date").groupby(["dim_1"])\
            .apply(lambda x: x["value"] - x["value"].shift()).reset_index(), 
        ["dim_1"])
```

Resulting in:

```
   dim_1       date  value
0      0 2017-01-01    NaN
1      1 2017-01-01    NaN
2      0 2017-01-02   20.0
3      1 2017-01-02   20.0
4      0 2017-01-03   80.0
5      1 2017-01-03  -10.0
6      0 2017-01-04  -20.0
7      1 2017-01-04   90.0
```

This issue does not arise, when I group by more than one dimension.

I assume that there is an easier way to achieve this result, but I am currently not able to find it.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`Groupby.diff()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) as a better alternative rather than computing the difference by shifting the index axis using `apply` which becomes less efficient as a result.

```
df.assign(value=df.groupby("dim_1")['value'].diff())
```

[image]